# How do I make wildcards work in a like operator in SQL Server reporting services?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportbuilder

I have added a filter expression using the like operator.  What do I put in the value field?  my parameter is named @test and I'd like the filter to function as a like %@test% would in SQL.  I want it to act like %@test% so I can pass '' to get all values for the query.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [T-SQL and the WHERE LIKE %Parameter% clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14237755/t-sql-and-the-where-like-parameter-clause)

Comment: @SayedAbolfazlFatemi that question is re: SQL, this is RE SQL Server Reporting Services which is different.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I got this to work by adding a filter expression with a like operator and setting the value to this:

```
="*" + Parameters!Roles.Value + "*"
```

To get all values I pass ''.

Answer (score 18):

You could also simply use string concatenation in the original Dataset that you want to filter on. You can access the parameters in the same manner as SQL:

```
WHERE fieldname LIKE '%' + @test + '%'
```

You can then link the report parameter @test to the @test in the dataset via the parameters option on Dataset Properties.

Comment: For those querying against Oracle, use:  WHERE fieldname LIKE '%' || :test || '%'

Answer (score 0):

You should use this Query in the DATA SECCTION of the REPORT WIZARD.

```
SELECT * FROM HR.JOBS WHERE JOB_TITLE LIKE  :JOB_TITLE | |'%'
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use this simple query.

```
WHERE fieldname LIKE CONCAT('%',@test,'%')
```

Used **CONCAT**

Answer (score 0):

You need to set Parameter Value with Like operator and that will work like a charm !
(use double quotes(") near following example instead of single quote(') as the editor was not allowing me to put double quotes with asterisk(*) symbol)

LIKE "asterisk" & Parameters!Roles.Value & "asterisk"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).