# Using LIKE (@parameter) in Report Builder Query

Tags: sql-server-2008, sharepoint, reportbuilder

I have a report in Report Builder that works fine with a Parameter Field (@job_no). I now wish to add a second parameter encapsulated inside a LIKE argument. Something along the lines of

> WHERE     (dbo.jm_job.job_no = (@job_no)) 
>   AND       (dbo.jm_work_order.wo_desc LIKE %'(@wo_desc)'%)

I've tried various styles or argument, but I'm missing something.
Thanks

Giles

Comment: Shouldn't that be `LIKE '%' || @wo_desc || '%'`?

Comment: again, trying various connertations, but still failing

Comment: SQL Server => `LIKE '%' + @wo_desc + '%'`  should work

Comment: An answer was provided over here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4898358/how-do-i-make-wildcards-work-in-a-like-operator-in-sql-server-reporting-services) I was looking for the same thing.
I don't believe this would work with 'multiple' values.

Answer (score 0):

To make it work in Oracle databases I found this way useful:

Oracle => `LIKE :ParameterName`
And define your parameter values as value and wildcards. (Parameter Properties > Parameter Values > Specify Values) ie: Label: `ParameterName`, Value: `ParameterValue%`

It worked for me with RRSS 2.0 and Oracle Client & Database 10

Comment: this topic is around sql-server, view tag "sql-server-2008"