# T-SQL and the WHERE LIKE %Parameter% clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, prepared-statement, sql-like

I was trying to write a statement which uses the WHERE LIKE '%text%' clause, but I am not receiving results when I try to use a parameter for the text.  For example, this works:

```
SELECT Employee WHERE LastName LIKE '%ning%'
```

This would return users Flenning, Manning, Ningle, etc.  But this statement would not:

```
DECLARE @LastName varchar(max)
SET @LastName = 'ning'
SELECT Employee WHERE LastName LIKE '%@LastName%'
```

No results found.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 211, accepted):

It should be:

```
...
WHERE LastName LIKE '%' + @LastName + '%';
```

Instead of:

```
...
WHERE LastName LIKE '%@LastName%'
```

Comment: thanks for the earlier tip on the question. But it wasn't though. Anyway [in the quest of a high performing answer - is this useful or not?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14243580/1389394) :)

Comment: @bonCodigo I don't know really, performance and optimization is not my area. Furthermore, these functions are vendor specific, in your case it depends on how the Oracle RDBMS evaluate them, and I don't know Oracle. Sorry.

Comment: This didn't work for me.  The % needs to be in the addParameter section.  See James Curran answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/251276/howto-parameters-and-like-statement-sql

Comment: see my answer (currently below). the wildcard-symbol is PART of the SEARCH expression, not part of the sql-query. It is entered by the USER (or, if wildcard-search is predefined, is appended to the users search expression input). If you append it via string concatanation on database-level, you get an unreusable query-string

Comment: This does not works correctly. Try two cases, one with hard-coded value after the like clause and another with parameter concat. Both fetching diff sets of results.

Answer (score 19):

you may try this one, used **CONCAT**

```
WHERE LastName LIKE Concat('%',@LastName,'%')
```

Answer (score 18):

The correct answer is, that, because the `'%'`-sign is part of your search expression, it should be part of your VALUE, so whereever you SET `@LastName` (be it from a programming language or from TSQL) you should set it to `'%' + [userinput] + '%'`

or, in your example:

```
DECLARE @LastName varchar(max)
SET @LastName = 'ning'
SELECT Employee WHERE LastName LIKE '%' + @LastName + '%'
```