# like case in inline query making error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

My inline sql query is like this

```
DataSet ds =  SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(GlobalSettings.DbDSN, CommandType.Text, 
   "SELECT TOP 1000 [ID],[Project],[Owner],[Consultant],[Contractor],[Value],
      [Level1], [Level2] ,[Status] ,[Category]  ,[Country],[CreatedDate],
      [CreatedByID], [CreatedByName] 
    FROM [DBname].[dbo].[tbl_Projects] 
    where [Category] like %@Category% 
      and Value=1000 
      and Country like'%Bahrain%' 
    order by CreatedDate",
new SqlParameter("@Category","oil")  );
```

everything looks okay to me .But it throws an error

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near 'Category'.
```

I believe it is something I had done wrong when using like query.
Can any one point out what went wrong?

Comment: You are missing the single quotes around `'%@Category%'`

Comment: Was my first thought, too, but @Category is a parameter.

Comment: You might as well use `WHERE CHARINDEX(@Category, [Category]) > 0` instead as you are adding both leading and trailing wildcards. Saves having to append them and also works correctly if your `@Category` value contains characters of special significance in a `LIKE` pattern without having to escape them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work

```
... LIKE '%' + @Category + '%'
```

cf. [T-SQL and the WHERE LIKE %Parameter% clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14237755/t-sql-and-the-where-like-parameter-clause)