# SQL declared variable as nvarchar. Use dec variable as 'like' or 'Contains' in where clause

Tags: sql, variables, where-clause, sql-like, contain

I have declared my variable:

```
declare @search as nvarchar
set @search = 'road'
```

Then I effectively want to have this in my Where clause:

```
where  

unit.BuildingName like '%@search%' or
property.Street like '%@search%' or
unit.Street like '%@search%'
```

Obviously not going to work as this isn't even looking at my declared variable.

But can you see what I am trying to get at?

Thanks!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [T-SQL and the WHERE LIKE %Parameter% clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14237755/t-sql-and-the-where-like-parameter-clause)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the query like this.

```
declare @search as nvarchar(500)
set @search = '%road%'

where  
unit.BuildingName like @search or
property.Street like @search or
unit.Street like @search
```

Answer (score 0):

`@search` in your query is being interpreted literally, instead of as a variable value.  You probably want this:

```
where  

unit.BuildingName like '%' + @search + '%' or
property.Street like '%' + @search + '%' or
unit.Street like '%' + @search + '%'
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm guessing that you are using SQL Server (based on the reference to `contains`), you need to do two things:

```
declare @search as nvarchar(255)
set @search = 'road';
```

Note the addition of a length.

Then:

```
where unit.BuildingName like '%' + @search + '%' or
      property.Street like '%' + @search + '%' or
      unit.Street like '%' + @search + '%'
```

If this is part of dynamic SQL, you should be passing `@search` in as a string, rather than munging the query string.

You might be able to simplify your logic to:

```
where (unit.BuildingName + property.Street + unit.Street) like '%' + @search + '%'
```