# Empty Dataset with SQLDataAdapter

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, dataset

There are 2 scenarios to check when executing this `SQL Select Statement` below..

```
retrieveQuery = "SELECT itemName, itemCategory, itemSubCategory, itemPrice, orders, (orders * itemPrice) as TotalPrice FROM Menu WHERE itemCategory = @selectedCat AND itemSubCategory LIKE '%@selectedSubCat%'";
```

The 2 fields in the parameterized query are `selectedCat` and `selectedSubCat`.

First scenario is when the user selects for only `Food` and as you can see the `DropdownList` Value selected is `ALL` which means to say that the query statement's `Where Clause` should have only `selectedCat = 'Food'` and `selectedSubCat LIKE '%%' (ALL VALUES OF FIELD 'itemSubCategory' FOUND IN THE SQL TABLE)`

[image: First Scenario]

Second scenario is when the user selects for only `Food` and selects the `DropdownList` Value to be `Donut` which means to say that the query statement's `Where Clause` should have only `selectedCat = 'Food'` and `selectedSubCat LIKE '%Donut%'`

[image: Second Scenario]

Upon when the user hits the `Export to PDF` button, these lines of codes are executed..
**I have removed the unnecessary codes**

```
  String itemCat = HF_TabListType.Value;
  String itemSubCatFood = ddlFood.SelectedValue;
  String itemSubCatBeverage = ddlBeverages.SelectedValue;

  //Retrieving Data to Populate to Report Table
  String strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
  SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
  myConn.Open();

  SqlDataAdapter da;
  DataSet dsPDF = new DataSet();

  String retrieveQuery = String.Empty;

  using (System.IO.MemoryStream memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
  {
      PdfPTable reportTable = new PdfPTable(1);
      if (itemCat == "Food" || itemCat == "Beverages")
      {
          reportTable = new PdfPTable(foodGV.Columns.Count - 1);
      }
      else if (itemCat == "Combo")
      {
          reportTable = new PdfPTable(gvCombo1Total.Columns.Count);
      }
      reportTable.TotalWidth = 1000f;
      reportTable.LockedWidth = true;
      reportTable.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
      reportTable.SpacingAfter = 30f;

      //For Food and Beverages
      String[] headerForFB = { "No.", "Item Name", "Item Category", "Item Sub Category", "Item Price($)", "Orders", "Total($)" };

      //Fod Combo
      String[] headerForC = { "No.", "Combo", "Total Amount of Orders", "Total Discounts($)", "Total Sales($)" };

      if (itemCat == "Food" || itemCat == "Beverages")
      {
          for (int i = 0; i < headerForFB.Length; i++)
          {
              PdfPCell hCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(headerForFB[i].ToString(), BoldFontForHeader));
              hCell.FixedHeight = 25f;
              reportTable.AddCell(hCell);
          }
      }
      else if (itemCat == "Combo")
      {
          for (int i = 0; i < headerForC.Length; i++)
          {
              PdfPCell hCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(headerForC[i].ToString(), BoldFontForHeader));
              reportTable.AddCell(hCell);
          }
      }

      retrieveQuery = "SELECT itemName, itemCategory, itemSubCategory, itemPrice, orders, (orders * itemPrice) as TotalPrice FROM Menu WHERE itemCategory = @selectedCat AND itemSubCategory LIKE '%@selectedSubCat%'";

      da = new SqlDataAdapter(retrieveQuery.ToString(), myConn);
      da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@selectedCat", itemCat);
      //da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("selectedSubCat", "%" + itemSubCatFood + "%");

      if (HF_TabListType.Value.ToString() == "Food")
      {
          if (ddlFood.SelectedIndex != 0)
          {
              da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@selectedSubCat", itemSubCatFood);
          }
          else
          {
              da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@selectedSubCat", "%%");
          }
      }
      else if (HF_TabListType.Value.ToString() == "Beverages")
      {
          if (ddlBeverages.SelectedIndex != 0)
          {
              da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@selectedSubCat", itemSubCatBeverage);
          }
          else
          {
              da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@selectedSubCat", "%%");
          }
      }

      da.Fill(dsPDF);

      GridView1.DataSource = dsPDF;
      GridView1.DataBind();

      PdfPCell cell = null;
      PdfPCell cellCount = null;
      int j = 0;

      //Food/Beverages
      if (dsPDF != null || dsPDF.Tables.Count != 0 || dsPDF.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0)
      {
          foreach (DataRow r in dsPDF.Tables[0].Rows)
          {
              cellCount = new PdfPCell(new Phrase((j + 1).ToString(), NormalFont));
              cellCount.FixedHeight = 15f;
              reportTable.AddCell(cellCount);

              for (int i = 0; i < dsPDF.Tables[0].Columns.Count; i++)
              {
                  cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(r[i].ToString(), NormalFont));
                  cell.FixedHeight = 15f;
                  reportTable.AddCell(cell);
              }

              j++;
          }
      }
```

When the PDF is generated the output of the PDF Table gives this..

[image: First Image]

Using the `Second Scenario` stated above,
I have tried to amend the codes and in some instances i got `2 rows with cells that are empty`. Meaning the `Dataset` produced has the `rows` and `columns` needed to set the `number of rows and columns` of the `PDF Table` respectively.

Could there be an issue with the Retrieve Statement? Or because of adding the `da.SelectCommand.Parameters` line into if else statements?

I have been trying to work this out for days..

Appreciate any help please, thanks!

Comment: I think the problem is with the construction of your retrieve query. [See this question for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14237755/t-sql-and-the-where-like-parameter-clause)

Comment: @JonSusiak i changed the sql statement to `retrieveQuery = "SELECT itemName, itemCategory, itemSubCategory, itemPrice, orders, (orders * itemPrice) as TotalPrice FROM Menu WHERE itemCategory = @selectedCat AND itemSubCategory LIKE '@selectedSubCat'";` and im using `da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@selectedSubCat", "%" + itemSubCatFood + "%");` but it still doesn't work..